# Checkbox can't change on click (Infinity function return)

Tags: reactjs, function

When you click on a checked checkbox, nothing happens, it doesn't change it to unchecked, does anyone know how to make that checkbox change?

I think it's because the function is still executed, so there's a loop and it returns "checked", so you can't click on it.

```
function checkCheckedOnEdit(id_data){
      if(filterListOnID)
      for(var i = 0; i < filterListOnID.length; i++) {
        if(filterListOnID[i].filter_name_id == id_data){
          return "checked";
        }
      }
     }
```

```
<label>Filtry</label>
                    { filterList && (
                      filterList.map(function(item, id) {
                          return(
                            <div className='filters-list'>
                              <input type="checkbox" {...register("admin_subcategory_edit_filters")} value={item.id} checked={checkCheckedOnEdit(item.id)} />
                              {item.name}
                            </div>
                      )}.bind(this))
                      )
                    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onChange listener:

```
const addItemToFilter = (id) => {
  if(!filterListOnID) return;

  const itemIndex = filterListOnID.findIndex(el => el.filter_name_id === id);

  if(itemIndex !== -1) return;
  setFilterListOnID([...filterListOnID, id]);
}

<input type="checkbox" {...register("admin_subcategory_edit_filters")} value= 
    {item.id} checked={checkCheckedOnEdit(item.id)} onChange={() => 
    addOrRemoveItemFromFilter(item.id) } />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for providing straight the whole code, it works fine, but if I click on the checkbox where it is not "checked" it will change fine, but the checkbox where it was "checked" will be removed one by one, you can Is there any way to keep those who have already been checked?

Comment: I edited the function. Now you can only select the checkbox and unselect does not work. Is this what you want?

Comment: Well, I have this problem that those who are not "checked" can be edited, but those that are automatically "checked" from the beginning cannot be changed to "unchecked"

Comment: I am showing on this video. https://www.veed.io/view/1c090817-f3c9-4b5a-a0c6-5a04fe826052

Comment: Do you know please?

Comment: Fixed. if(itemIndex == -1) return setFilterListOnID((prevBenefits) => [... prevBenefits, id]);